# Ubuntu 12 installation problem

Tags: installation, kernel

I have made about 30 copies of the Ubuntu installation CD, but there is no way to install it on my laptop. 
I get a black screen with a blinking cursor or I get a /casper/vmlinuz file not found
or I get Invalid or corrupt kernel image.
I tried all solutions that I found but no way to install ubuntu on this laptop.
I tried both 32 bit and 64 bit versions, I tried ubuntu 11, and no way to install it.

Only If I install windows first and than can I install it with wubi. But that is not an ideal solution. That is linux installed on windows.

If I install any other distributions of linux the installation works ok. So there must be some issue with ubuntu!

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 or Ubuntu 12.10? If 12.04 you need a CD of at least 80 min (732 MB size) if 12.10 you need a DVD (800 MB size)

Answer (score 0):

If you realy used a CD and not a DVD then that might be the problem cause latest Ubuntu versions need DVD, a CD is not enough. have you tried with a USB boot?